# istream operator overloading without function body? what does it mean?

Tags: c++

```
__istream_type&
operator>>(bool& __n)
{ return _M_extract(__n); }

__istream_type&
operator>>(short& __n);

__istream_type&
operator>>(unsigned short& __n)
{ return _M_extract(__n); }

__istream_type&
operator>>(int& __n);
```

The above code snip comes from libstdc++, which is basically a bunch of operator overloading for >>.
My question is for **short** and **int** types, there are not function bodies. Then what does the function do in these cases? Is there a default routing for those functions that have no function body?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a just an ordinary class method declaration. Nothing out of the ordinary.

When you write your own classes, you must've done the same thing yourself, many times:

```
class my_class {

      // ...

      void some_method();
};
```

and then later defined

```
void my_class::some_method()
{
      // stuff
}
```

And this is exactly the same thing, here. If you keep reading the header file, you will see

```
#include <bits/istream.tcc>
```

tucked away at the end of it.

And if you peruse the contents of this file, you will discover the definition:

```
 template<typename _CharT, typename _Traits>
    basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>&
    basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::
    operator>>(short& __n)
    {
          // ...
```

And that's the class method you're looking for.